# FormData doesn`t work when I try to append

Tags: javascript, form-data

In Google Chorome's DevTool I try to do that:

```
var fd = new FormData();
fd.append('newField', 'someValue');
```

but fd still is empty. Any Idea?

Comment: How do you know its empty?

Comment: I tried with console.log but just get FormData's object empty.
I tried with xhr, sending the formData but nothing. 
I tried with fd.get('newField') but not supported, I had Chrome v49

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
fd.get('newField');
```

The above will return `'someValue'`.

You should note that it is supported on Chrome v50 and firefox v39. See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) for support.

Comment: Doesnt work, the console shows: Uncaught TypeError: fd.get is not a function(...)

Comment: It works on chrome after version 50. Check which version of chrome you are using. It works in firefox version 39.